# Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, charts, composer-php

I want to put a pie chart on my laravel project and install a library consoleTvs. But I decided to remove it from composer since I use a jquery instead.

When i try to run my project I use to have a error message

> Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider' not found.

Comment: Do a search in the directory of your project and find where you are using ChartsServiceProvider. Something like what I think Leonardo says to you. In some file may have been an `use App\Providers\ChartsServiceProvider;`

Comment: For example, in PhpStorm, if I right click on the root directory of my project, a menu appears with the option 'Find in Path ...'. If I press there and type 'ChartsServiceProvider', the IDE will search throughout the project where that word appears. Several IDEs have a tool like this, or maybe the file manager of your system has it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing ANY code it's very hard to help you.
I try to guess: you are not importing `ChartsServiceProvider` class so, still guessing, you can put at the start of your file

```
use App\Providers\ChartsServiceProvider;
```

Comment: I uninstall the chart library from composer. remove the provider and alias in app.php under config but i still get the error Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 0):

So now you want to remove a library from `composer`.
i hope you remove it correctly. still you can follow below how to remove.

so remove that library code into your composer.json. and hit `composer update`.

so Hope you remove it correctly, so after removal you facing error of provider.
I guess on the time of installing you manually add a provider into your `app.php` file inside `config` folder.

So if, Am right, just go to your `app.php` file inside `config` folder and remove that provider as well as its alias too if you give it before.

Comment: I did remove the provider as well as it aliases but still the problem exists.

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider' not found